# Matrix Multiplication issues

Tags: c++, matrix, multiplication

I have implemented a matrix class. It dynamically allocates memory for an arbitrarily sized matrix.When using my matrix multiplication function, it only works under specific conditions. If you have two N*M matrices, M of the first matrix must equal N of the second matrix. 
Example:

```
//matrix constructor 'matrix M(n, m)
matrix A(2, 3), matrix B(3, 4);
//A and B can be multiplied because A_m == B_n
A * B; //this works!
//changing the size of n of the first matrix causes this to fail if n > m 
matrix C(4, 3), matrix D(3, 5);
C * D; // program becomes unresponsive for unknown reasons, only happens when C_n > C_m
```

My matrix class and the multiplication function.

```
#include <iostream> 
class matrix{
    private:
        int rows, cols;
    public:
        int ** data;
        int row();
        int col();
        matrix();
        matrix(int, int);
        //~matrix();
        matrix operator*(matrix M);
        matrix operator%(matrix M);
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, matrix M);      
};
```

Functions:

```
#include "matrix.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

matrix::matrix(int r, int c){
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    data = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i< rows; i++){
        data[i] = new int[cols];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            data[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

matrix::row(){
    return rows;
}

matrix::col(){
    return cols;
}

matrix matrix::operator*(matrix M){
    if (this->col() == M.row()){
        matrix result(this->row(), M.col());
        int var = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.row(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < result.col(); j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < result.row(); k++){
                    var += this->data[i][k] * M.data[k][j];
                } 
            result.data[i][j] = var;
            var = 0;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    else cout << "FAILED";
} 

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, matrix M){
    for (int i = 0; i < M.row(); i++){
        os << '|';
        for (int j = 0; j < M.col(); j++){
            os << M.data[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        os << "|\n";
    }
    os << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Why is the program not working under these circumstances?

Comment: The good news is, you don't have a [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) problem in this code because you're implementing *none* of the destructor, copy-ctor, or copy-assignment operator. The bad news is, the *reason* it isn't a problem is because it leaks like a sieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, props for

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

Good to see someone not pulling in all of std for a simple job like this.

Now let's take a walk through the algorithm.

matrix C(4, 3) * matrix D(3, 5) will give matrix result (4,5)

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.row(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < result.col(); j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < result.row(); k++){
```

resolves to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
            var += this->data[i][k] * M.data[k][j];
Array size:                   4  3           3  5
```

k is going to run 0 .. 3. Valid range for k is 0 .. 2.

What you want is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.row(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < result.col(); j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < this->cols; k++){
```

Three suggestions:

Learn to use a debugger. This sort of problem is utterly trivial if you step through the code.

Then learn to test with testable inputs so you can see when the math does not work. Multiplying 0 by 0 will prove absolutely nothing.

I recommend replacing

```
int ** data;
```

with

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;
```

You can initialize it in a constructor like this:

```
matrix::matrix(int r, int c):rows(r), cols(c), data(r, std::vector<int>(c))
{
}
```

No need to loop through it to zero it. The vector constructor does it for you. If you don't want to load with zeroes, you can specify another value.

```
matrix::matrix(int r, int c):
    rows(r), 
    cols(c), 
    data(r, std::vector<int>(c, <starting value goes here>))
{
}
```

Comment: As a bonus, using the `std::vector<>` approach makes the class rule-of-three compliant by-default. The `,0` is not required, but that is so trife it is barely worth mentioning. Also, though it doesn't affect this code, it should be noted the order of initializers in that member list is *not* left-to-right. `rows`, then `cols`, then `data` will be the initialization order per the order of the members in the class decl.

Comment: Yeah, that 0 is pretty much useless. I'll edit to make it clear why you might want to specify a value there. And fudge. I did get the order wrong. I was looking at the row and col functions.

Comment: This is excellent. Clearly addresses the issue and provides a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These 3 loops are accessing memory out of allocated blocks to your code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.row(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < result.col(); j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < result.row(); k++){
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.row(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < M.col(); j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < M.row(); k++){
                var += this->data[i][k] * M.data[k][j];
            }
            result.data[i][j] = var;
            var = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Think about what this does when multiplying a 1x1 matrix against a 1x1 matrix

Comment: I don't think OP is looking at the output of his function.

Comment: @user4581301 I have serious reservations to that end as well. The example I suggested would result in no multiplications at all and a 1x1 matrix with a single value of zero regardless of the operands if the proposed solution here is used. That is obviously *not* correct.

Comment: I see now that this could not work, always makes the bottom row set to 0's

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will work.

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
    class Matrix{

        int rs, cs;
        T **mat;
    public:
        Matrix() { mat = NULL; rs = cs = 0; }
        istream& operator>>( Matrix <T> &);
        ofstream& operator<<(const Matrix<T> &);
        Matrix<T> operator=(const Matrix<T> &);
        Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> &);
        void read();
        void print();

    };
    template <typename T>
    Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix<T> &a){
        if(this->mat!=NULL)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < this->rs ; i++)
                delete []mat;
        }
        this->rs = a.rs;
        this->cs = a.cs;
        this->mat = new T*[a.rs];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < a.rs; i++)
            this->mat[i] = new T[a.cs];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < a.rs ; i++){
            for(int k = 0 ; k < a.cs; k++)
                this->mat[i][k] =a.mat[i][k];
        }
        return a;
    }
    template <typename T>
    Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(const Matrix<T> &a){
        Matrix<T> b;
        b.rs = this->rs;
        b.cs = a.cs;
        if(this->cs == a.rs){
            b.mat = new T*[b.rs];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < this->rs; i++)
                b.mat[i] = new T[b.cs];

            for(int i = 0 ; i < this->rs; i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0 ; k < a.cs ; k++){
                    b.mat[i][k] = 0;
                    for(int j = 0 ; j < this->cs ; j++)
                        b.mat[i][k] += this->mat[i][j] * a.mat[j][k];
                }
            }
            return b;
        }
        else
        {
               cout<<"You can not multiply these matrices"<<endl;
               b.mat = new T*[b.rs];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < this->rs; i++)
                b.mat[i] = new T[b.cs];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < b.rs ; i++)
                for(int k = 0 ; k < b.cs ; k++)
                    b.mat[i][k] =0;
            return b;
        }

    }
    template <typename T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream &g ,  Matrix<T> &a);
    template <typename T>
    istream& operator>>(istream &g , Matrix<T> &a);
    int main(){
         Matrix <int > A, B, C;
         Matrix < double > M, R, S;
         cin >> A;
         cin>>C;
         B = A*C;
         cout<<endl<<B<<endl;
    }
    template <typename T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream &g ,  Matrix<T> &a){
        a.print();
        return g;
    }
    template <typename T>
    void Matrix<T>::print(){
    for(int i = 0; i < rs ;i++){
            for(int k = 0 ; k < cs ; k++){
                cout<<mat[i][k]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    template <typename T>
    istream& operator>>(istream &g , Matrix<T> &a)
    {
        a.read();
        return g;
    }
    template <typename T>

    void Matrix<T>::read()
    {
        if (mat!=NULL) {
          for(int i = 0 ; i < rs ; i++)
            delete []mat;
        }
        cout<<"Enter row size: ";
        cin >> rs;
        cout<<"Enter column size: ";
        cin>> cs;
        int i;
        mat = new T*[rs];
        for (i = 0; i < rs; i++)
            mat[i] = new T[cs];
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < rs; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < cs; j++)
            {
                cout<<"Element ["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] = ";
                cin >> mat[i][j];
            }
        }

    }
```